# C# Method signature object reference

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a base class and child like this:

```
class BaseType
{
   string Name{get;set;}
   string AddressLine1 {get;set;}
   string PostalCode {get;set;}
}


class ChildType : BaseType
{
    string extrafield {get;set;}
}
```

**Edit:**

My custom Update method is the same for both objects for all but the one extra field. These objects are used in WCF services, so reusing a custom SET WCF Service is what I'm trying to do.

So I would pass in either a `BaseType` or a `ChildType`; be able to access the base properties for either object and do what ever logic.

I'm trying to reduce duplication of code.

Comment: Those are properties, not fields. The two terms aren't interchangeable. Anyway, what update method and what SET method are you referring to?

Comment: Don't do it this way.  Make the Set() method virtual so you can override it in the derived class.  It can call base.Set() for the three base properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `BaseType` for the argument to the method:

```
void DoSomethingWithType(BaseType instance)
{
    // Do something here..
    Console.WriteLine(instance.Name);
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
ChildType child = new ChildType() { Name = "Foo"; }
DoSomethingWithType(child);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void SetMethod(BaseType obj)
{
    obj.Name = ...
    obj.AddressLise1 = ..
    obj.PostalCode = ...
    if (obj is ChildType)
    {
        ((ChildType)obj).extraField = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Reed it was just an example. There is no indication of what the "update method" or the "set method" looks like in the question.

Comment: @Tigran forgot to put my c# cap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure i understand what "update method" you're reffering to, but in general auto properties can't be customized in any way. you can however put whatever code you want in the setter of a property, as long as you make your own backing field for it.

All properties have a set type though, the only way you can assign another type is if that type is assignable to the property type.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good case for the "is" keyword.

```
void doSomething(BaseType b)
{
   if (b is ChildType)
   {
     // stuff with ChildType's extra properties  
   }
}
```

[is keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: If this is a class and not a value type then `as` and a null check would be a better choice.  Slightly faster and already cast to the proper type inside of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to understand what do you exactly need. If my guess is correct, then you should do something like (checking for type of the instance within method is generally bad practice):

```
void Update(BaseType obj)
{
    obj.Name = "aaa";
    obj.PostalCode = "123556";
}

void Update(ChildType obj)
{
    b.ExtraField = "extra";
    Update((BaseType)obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I am reading the question correctly, but I'll give it a shot, taking my cue from this line: "So I would pass in either a BaseType or a ChildType; be able to access the base properties for either object and do what ever logic."

So let's assume a function foo that takes a parameter.

If you have `foo(BaseType b)` then:

- You can be passed an instance of either BaseType or ChildType
- You can access all properties defined on BaseType
- BUT you cannot access the extrafield member without ridiculous casting shenanigans

This is for a very good reason: your function takes BaseType, which has no extrafield, so since it doesn't exist you can't refer to it.

If that's okay, then just do this.  If you need to access extrafield then you have a small problem.

The alternate form of foo is `foo(ChildType c)` which will mean:

- You can only accept instances of ChildType, not instances of BaseType
- BUT you can access any of the properties, including Name and extrafield

The solution I would first consider here is to extend the signature of BaseType to include extrafield.  Polymorphism works best when your signature is consistent across the various levels of the class hierarchy that you want to treat interchangeably.  Even if extrafield doesn't make a ton of sense in BaseType you may wish to either make BaseType abstract, or put a no-op implementation of the extrafield there.

I would say that if your design calls for having a different signature for the subclass, you will encounter difficulties in treating it as totally interchangeable with the BaseType.

Comment: Which is fine. I just want one operation to be used for the 'BASE' types.